# X3 Terran Conflict runs out of memory after about an hour and becomes unplayable

Tags: technical-issues, x3-terran-conflict

I am running the latest version of X3 Terran Conflict (3.1) and after about 30 min - 1 hour or so (depending on what I do - I think visiting more sectors triggers it faster) in a brand new game its memory usage goes well above 2 GB. I only have 4 GB of RAM, running Windows 7 64 bit. As a result of X3 using more RAM than is available, my hard drive starts paging and makes the game and other applications become unusable. I have to restart the game.

Is anyone aware of this issue or how to fix it?

Is this a bug in the game? I'm using some mods but most are pretty simple and don't add maps and such.

The mods I am using are:

- [SCR] [25.01.2009] [V3.7.1] Dead Space 2LootTransporter
- [SCR] MARS Fire Control
- [SCR]Asteroid Creator TC (28.11.2008)
- [SCRIPT] Auto prep ships v1.2.1 [2009-07-30]
- [SCRIPT] Manual Trade Extension v2.1.1 [2009-08-06]
- [SCRIPT] Marine Training Manager Updated - v3 12232008
- [SCRIPT] Player Workshops V2.0 [28.07.2009] - add upgrades auto equipable at player stations
- [SCRIPT] Rotate and Move Objects
- [SCRIPT]Launch Fighter Drone Hotkey
- broadcast return home to all owned ships for carriers and stations
- Capital ship energy cell generator
- Launch Marines With Hotkey
- LazCorp Claim Derelict Ship
- marine repairs
- My own PHQ Mod, which just modifies the XML to increase storage Dead Space 2 and only use money to build blueprints
- Player headquarters buy-able in boron shipyards needed for custom games
- [SCRIPT] Community Configuration Menu  V1.20  03062009
- Ware Blueprint Manager 2.1 - Blueprint any ware at PHQ, upgrade PHQ
- [SCRIPT] X3TC Cheat Package - Only until i get back most of the stuff i had in a previous saved game.  I started a new game to get the map fixes. I think i was pre 2.5 before.  I hope this mod is causing the issue as i don't plan to use it much longer.
- [Script][Mar 13 2009] Station Storage Extension

Note that I have my previous save which I played for 16 days on Windows XP in the past on version 2.1 (I believe) of X3 and I don't remember having any issue like this. Back then I am pretty sure I was running with all the mods above except the following:

- Ware Blueprint Manager 2.1 - Blueprint any ware at PHQ, upgrade PHQ
- [SCRIPT] X3TC Cheat Package

Is anyone aware of any memory leaks or issues from any of the mods above (including the ones I played with on windows XP)?

I am using X Plugin Manager Lite v 1.20 to install most of the mods (the ones with spk files), on my xp machine i was using XPluginManager 2.20 beta 6 (which i think is the original version of X Plugin Manager Lite before the rewrite).

Also does the order of enabling mods matter? I enabled a few mods before i enabled
* [SCRIPT] Community Configuration Menu  V1.20  03062009
But i only started the game once they were all enabled.

Comment: You're better off posting this on the Egosoft forums.

Comment: most likely it is the effect of one of the mods you have installed that is causing a memory leak.  I have left x3:TC running for weeks at a time before without issues on windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, one or more of your scripts have memory leaks.  Worse, it's highly likely that their mutual interaction is making things worse rather than better (so it's also effectively impossible for us to say "yes, this is the bad one").

First, I would ensure that you have the very latest patch.  That has fixed many stability issues: I haven't had memory issues in the unmodded game for months.

If that doesn't fix things, you're going to have to work up from a clean install and test each mod.

If you're already thinking of getting rid of a mod, I wouldn't bother testing it:

> [SCRIPT] X3TC Cheat Package - Only until i get back most of the stuff
>   i had in a previous saved game. I started a new game to get the map
>   fixes. I think i was pre 2.5 before. I hope this mod is causing the
>   issue as i don't plan to use it much longer.

Not to be mean but I would also suggest removing any of your own mods.  I always start by assuming that new bugs in software were caused by me.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at mods which utilize fake patches (pair of numbered cat/dat files in main directory). I had an issue where after extended gameplay game would freeze completely, and then skyrocket from whichever memory mark it is on to 4Gb, then crash. After I've gone through all my mods, I found out that the issue is with the mods which require fake patch to be added.